# TensorFlow: How Can I get the total_cm in tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently using tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou to compute the IoU precision. This function returns only mean_iou while I want precision for each class.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tf.contrib.metrics.confusion_matrix](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard8/tf.contrib.metrics.confusion_matrix.md) looks like what you need. Once you have the confusion matrix, you can [use that to compute the precision for each class](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-to-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-confus).

Comment: Yes it works. Meanwhile I found this function [streaming_mean_iou](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops/metric_ops.py#L2732) works the same way and that there is a local variable [total_confusion_matrix](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops/metric_ops.py#L2786), which is added into the [LOCAL_VARIABLES](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops/metric_ops.py#L99) collection. Is there a way to access a local variable?

Comment: I think I get it. I can use tf.local_variables() to get all local variables. While there is only one local variable in my program, I get it. If there are more variables, I could filter their names to get the variable I want.

Comment: You could also use tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name, which I think should work for local variables (i.e. get_tensor_by_name called on your Graph object, often accessible through tf.get_default_graph()).