# Can anyone give an example on how tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou in tensorflow works?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow 0.11 and am running some image segmentation tests. In image segmentation, we usually compute the IoU. How can I make use of tensorflow's tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou?

```js
mIoU, confusionMatrix = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou(pred_labels_vec,gt_labels_vec,NUM_CLASS)

init = tf.initialize_local_variables()

sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
  iou, _ = sess.run([mIoU, confusionMatrix])
  print(iou)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct to compute the mean iou.

If you want to compute the IoU for each class, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340728/tensorflow-how-can-i-get-the-total-cm-in-tf-contrib-metrics-streaming-mean-iou). You can compute them via the confusion matrix. When you run `streaming_mean_iou`, tensorflow has already created a local variable, called [total_confusion_matrix](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py#L263) (same for tf 0.11). Then you can get this matrix by calling `tf.local_variables()`, or through `get_tensor_by_name`.

Comment: is it possible for iou to have negative values? I am not sure why I am getting nevergative values.

Comment: I am not sure either... maybe these could help you: (1) check if predications and labels have same range of num_classes; (2) check values of confusion matrix are normal; (3) whether you used `weights` or `masks` when computing mIoU, and check their values.